# Sound from browsers with javascript buggy on HTC Desire?

Tags: htc-desire, htc-sense, browser, audio, javascript

I'm trying to stream music from [The Hype Machine](http://hypem.com/#!/popular) on my HTC Desire.

When using the HTC Sense stock browser I can press play, go to

menu → ... → settings → site specific settings → back out until l I arrive at the site again

Only then the music will start playing.
If I activate the key lock or take the focus away in any other way, the sound will stop.

When using Opera Mobile I can't seem to get the sound to work at all.

Looking at the site's source the streaming is done with Javascript (mootools).
On my desktop I don't get any javascript errors and the site works perfectly fine.

Can anybody tell me why I have to jump through such hoops with the stock browser to get the sound going, how I can have the browser keep playing in the background or with the key lock on or why the sound doesn't seem to work in the otherwise nice Opera Mobile?

Comment: I don't know if it's even possible to have the media stream continue when the browser loses focus. Youtube videos, for example, do the same thing (stop playing when the browser loses focus).

Comment: eldarerathis is right.  This is to prevent page ads fron draining your battery when you're not using the phone (for example), page execution is stopped.

Comment: I understand the reason, but that's also an argument against web apps vs native apps.

Comment: You should take it up with Google ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is to prevent page ads fron draining your battery when you're not using the phone (for example), page execution is stopped.

As for Opera, I believe they have their own JavaScript engine, so maybe it's not standards-compliant.  Or maybe it doesn't interface well with the Android sound system.  Or maybe the page's JavaScript isn't standards-compliant.